# Sphinx is not creating cross-reference link

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference

Any ideas Why sphinx is not creating cross reference links?

I have tried every possible combination to try to get a link to work, no luck.
I have tried with the `napoleon_google_docstring` on and off.

Other references that are create automatically are working ok.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using straight single quotes instead of backticks to delimit the role content. For example, `:func:'atest'` must be changed to `` :func:`atest` ``.

References:

- http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/markup/inline.html
- http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#interpreted-text